# Source for Volozhiner Yeshiva Story

Tags: sources-mekorot, tzedakah-charity

[Many](https://torah.org/torah-portion/ravfrand-5772-vayakhel/) [trustworthy](https://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/1409977/jewish/The-Flashy-Fundraiser.htm) [sources](https://ytbb.co.il/%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%99-%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9-%D7%94%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%91%D7%94/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A2/%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A2-%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%97%D7%A8-%D7%93%D7%95%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%90-%D7%91%D7%A6%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%9C-%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95-%D7%9C%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%AA/) quote a story of Rav Chaim Volozhiner explaining to a disappointed benefactor that tzedakah given with pure intentions is used for holier items in the yeshiva while tzedakah given with less altruistic reasons (honor, fame, etc.) is used for less holy items.

Where is the source of the story? (Note: The third source quotes חידושי הגרי"ז החדשים, but I can't locate such a sefer.)

Comment: If I were to guess, I would say the חידושי הגרי"ז החדשים, is what they put in the back of the fancy בית הלוי.

Comment: I got around to checking the citation, it is there in the back of the fancy בית הלוי.

Comment: @Avrah Just curious, why don't you post this as an answer?

Comment: Just because it's printed doesn't mean that's the source.

Comment: The story is quoted and cited at the bottom of [this page](https://ytbb.co.il/%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%99-%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9-%D7%94%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%91%D7%94/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A2/%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A2-%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%97%D7%A8-%D7%93%D7%95%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%90-%D7%91%D7%A6%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%9C-%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95-%D7%9C%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%AA/).